# about topological manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

A fundamental theorem in Topology asserts that if $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $V \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ are homeomorphic, then $m=n$.

[image]

(i)- for above shape , try to write a description in terms of familiar topological spaces.

(ii)- Prove that a sphere with a hair (above shape), is not a topological manifold.

for (ii) we have :A connected manifold has a unique dimension $n$, and every point of $X$ then has an open neighbourhood homeomorphic to the open unit  ball  $\mathbb D^n\subset \mathbb R^n$.

However in the pictured $X$ the points different from $q$  on the hair have an open neigbourhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb D^1$ , whereas the points different from $q$  on the sphere have an open neigbourhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb D^2$.

Since $X$ is connected this proves that it is not a manifold, since it cannot have a unique dimension.so above shape is not a topological manifold.

> how we can answer first question ? also we know that above shape is homeomorphic to sphere and sphere is topological manifold but above shape is not a topological manifold .so we find two homeomorphic space such that one of them is is not a topological manifold and other is a topological manifold. is this true ?

Comment: You really don't need to use such a strong result as the uniqueness of the dimension to see that the sphere with a hair is not a manifold. You can argue directly that $q$ has no neighborhood homeomorphic to an open subset of Euclidean space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the space $X$. You can write the space as a glueing of a sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ and a half open interval

$$ X = \mathbb{S}^2 \coprod_{q = 0} [0,1)$$

In other words, $X$ is the pushout of the maps $\{\ast\} \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$ given by $\ast \mapsto q$ and $\{\ast\} \rightarrow [0,1)$ given by $\ast \mapsto 0$.

Comment: what is definition of ''glueing ''

Comment: Another description of "pushout". A glueing of two spaces is a quotient of their disjoint union where specified points are identified. Intuitively speaking, you "glue" the hair to the sphere at one point

Comment: also we know that above shape is homeomorphic to sphere and sphere is topological manifold but above shape is not a topological manifold .so we find two homeomorphic space such that one of them is is not a topological manifold and other is a topological manifold. is this true ?

Comment: @amirbahadory no, $X$ is not homeomorphic to the sphere. It is homotopy equivalent to it though

Comment: @amirbahadory if a manifold is homeomorphic to some other topological space $Y$, then this space is also a topological manifold.

Comment: why $X$ is not homeomorphic to the sphere ?

Comment: @amirbahadory assume there was. Then pick a point $x$ on the hair and map it along this homeomprphism to a point $p$ on the sphere. But $x$ has a neighborhood which is homeomorphic to $D^1$, and $p$ does not.